# How can I use objects in other classes?

Tags: java, methods, constructor

So I just started with java, so this is just a simple problem ig, but I have to make a small project for school. I made 2 classes, one called Pokémon and one called trainer. In the Pokémon class I made a constructor and a method to create objects, because I couldn't just create the object:

```
    public class Pokemon {

    public String name;
    public String typ;
    public int maxLp;
    public int aktLp;
    public int ap;

    public Pokemon(String pname, String ptyp, int pmaxLp, int paktLp, int pap) {
        name=pname;
        typ=ptyp;
        maxLp=pmaxLp;
        aktLp=paktLp;
        ap=pap;
    }
    
    public void CreatePokemon(String[] args) {
    Pokemon Squirtle = new Pokemon("Squirtle", "Water", 20, 20, 5);
    Pokemon Charmander = new Pokemon("Charmander", "Fire", 20, 20, 5);
   }
}
```

In the other class, Trainer, I wanted to use these created objects (Pokemon Squirtle and Pokemon Charmander) to let them fight, the "fight" is basically just one pokemon, I wanted to use Squirtle in the function Squirtle attack, attacking Charmander dealing as much damage as declared in ap, changing the variable aktLp in the object Glumanda, which is the current hp of glumanda:

```
public class Trainer
{

    public String name;
    public String gender;
    public int money;
    public int amountPokemon;
    public int amountFights;
    
    public Trainer(String tname, String tgender, int tmoney, int tamountPokemon, int tamountFights) {
        name=tname;
        gender=tgender;
        money=tmoney;
        amountPokemon=tamountPokemon;
        amountFights=tamountFights;
    }
    
    public void ChooseSquirtle() {
        System.out.println("You choose Squirtle!");
    }
    
    public void ChooseCharmander() {
        System.out.println("You choose Charmander!");
    }
    
    public void SquirtleAttack() {
        System.out.println("Squirtle attacks Charmander!");
        Charmander.aktLp = Charmander.aktLp - Squirtle.ap;
    }
}
```

So for this project I have to use - even if I don't like it - BlueJ. BlueJ says: "cannot find symbol - variable Glumanda" - but why? Do I have to call the method CreatePokemon() ? Well I thought I had to and added CreatePokemon(); ,pressed compile and there was another error, but there is no explanation whatsoever. I can't find the problem even though it might be easy. As I said I pretty much just started with java so tips are appreciated - also, I tried my best translating the variables, sorry if you don't understand them and if they are inacurrate.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code which is getting the error.  You haven't actually included anything that defines or attempts to use anything called "Glumanda".

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not very abstract and has a few flaws:

- You're creating pokemon object inside the pokemon class definition. What you should do instead is create it in some higher level method, e.g.: `main`.
- The trainer class uses two pokemons to attack each other. The problem is, the pokemon classes have not been instantiated in a scope that trainer can access. What you should do instead is either instantiate a new pokemon inside the trainer class, or pass pokemon objects as parameters to the generic attack function.

The trainer class could like this with instantiating new pokemon inside.

```java
class Trainer {

    public String name;
    public String gender;
    public int money;
    public int amountPokemon;
    public int amountFights;
    private Pokemon squirtle;
    private Pokemon charmander;

    public Trainer(String tname, String tgender, int tmoney, int tamountPokemon, int tamountFights) {
        name = tname;
        gender = tgender;
        money = tmoney;
        amountPokemon = tamountPokemon;
        amountFights = tamountFights;
        squirtle = new Pokemon("Squirtle", "Water", 20, 20, 5);
        charmander = new Pokemon("Charmander", "Fire", 20, 20, 5);

    }

    public void ChooseSquirtle() {
        System.out.println("You choose Squirtle!");
    }

    public void ChooseCharmander() {
        System.out.println("You choose Charmander!");
    }

    public void SquirtleAttack() {
        System.out.println("Squirtle attacks Charmander!");
        charmander.aktLp = charmander.aktLp - squirtle.ap;
    }
}
```

Or like this with accepting pokemons as parameters:

```java
class Trainer {

    public String name;
    public String gender;
    public int money;
    public int amountPokemon;
    public int amountFights;

    public Trainer(String tname, String tgender, int tmoney, int tamountPokemon, int tamountFights) {
        name = tname;
        gender = tgender;
        money = tmoney;
        amountPokemon = tamountPokemon;
        amountFights = tamountFights;

    }
    
    public void SquirtleAttack(Pokemon attacker, Pokemon defender) {
        System.out.println(attacker.name+" attacks "+defender.name+"!");
        defender.aktLp = defender.aktLp - attacker.ap;
    }
}


public class Main {
    public void CreatePokemon(String[] args) {

        Pokemon squirtle;
        Pokemon charmander;

        squirtle = new Pokemon("Squirtle", "Water", 20, 20, 5);
        charmander = new Pokemon("Charmander", "Fire", 20, 20, 5);
    }
}
```

Just a couple of hints:

- Not sure what your project structure is, but you cannot have 2 public classes in a single file. Public class has to have the same name as filename. You can, however, have multiple non-public classes in a single file. But generally it is not recommended to define multiple classes in a single file anyways.
- Per Java naming conventions, you should name variables or object instances beggining with lowercase letter. Read more: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html
- Try to use public class properties as least as possible and private as often as possible. To manipulate private properties values, use **getters** and **setters**. more info here: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/java-getters-and-setters/